# select all div - div hello and children jquery

Tags: jquery

how to select all elements except the div "hola" and childrens

```
     <body>
        <div id="hola">
            <div>example</div>
            <span>example</span>
        </div>
        <div>not selected</div>
        <span>not selected</span>
    </body>
```

---

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(":not(#hola > *)").click(function(){
            console.log("sdf");
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mp9f4/

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand your question.

Comment: how to select all elements except the div "hola" and childrens

Comment: Should I make this an answer for you to accept, giving an explanation as well?

Comment: if you please post a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you actually want not to select all items, but to process clicks on any item but the ones in `#hola` div (the element itself and its children).

Alas, the way you've chosen - assigning separate click handlers for all the elements but `#hola` and its children - is destined to fail, as click events [bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing).

I'd suggest slightly different approach: use just a single event handler placed on `document` (as you need to listen for clicks on all the elements), and within this handler check for the event's real target. For example:

```
  $(document).click(function(e) {
     var $target = $(e.target);
     if ($target.is('#hola') || $target.closest('#hola').length) {
       return false;
     }
     console.log('sdf');
   });
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TnJgr/).

Comment: It is okay to put a click event on the whole document, and check and stop the bubble, but it is way messier than just using the right selector.

Answer (score 2):

I pretty sure you don't want to select *all* other items, since that would include `body`.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("body > *:not(#hola)").click(function(){
        console.log("sdf");
    });
});
```

It selects all immediate children of `body`, except for ones with id `hola`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93hVm/)